# Expected value of Bernoulli variable (for Linear regression model)

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Can anybody explain how the following reduction happens:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \|y - (R*X) w\|^2
&= p \|y - X w\|^2 + (1-p) \|y\|^2
\\
&= p(\|y\|^2 - 2 y^\top X w + \|Xw\|^2) + (1-p) \|y\|^2
\\
&= (\|y\|^2 - 2 y^\top (p X w) + p^2 \|Xw\|^2) - p^2 \|Xw\|^2 + p \|Xw\|^2
\\
&= \|y - pXw\|^2 + p(1-p) \|Xw\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful. Would you please give me a clue what is happened in the first line? Is it Bernoulli property?

Comment: @Amir I used [the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) with the two cases $R=0$ and $R=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.